# Inner classes, wrong output

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm just going through inner classes but I'm getting the wrong output.

I'm basically trying to create a student object with two different addresses using an address class but I'm getting some ridiculous output.  I'm clearly doing something completely wrong so if anyone could help that would be brilliant.

Student class:

```
public class  Student {
    private String name;
    private Address homeAddress, uniAddress;

    public Student(String name, int houseNumber, String homeStreet, int uniNumber, String      uniStreet) {
        this.name = name;
        homeAddress = new Address(houseNumber, homeStreet);
        uniAddress = new Address(uniNumber, uniStreet);

   }

   public void setUniAddress (Address uniAddress){

       this.uniAddress = uniAddress;

   }

   public class Address {
        public int number;
        private String street;

        public Address(int no, String street) {
            number = no;
            this.street = street;
        }
   }

   public String toString()     {

        String a = name + "\n" + homeAddress + " " + uniAddress;
        return a;
   }
}
```

and my test student class to create the object and to run the toString:

```
 public class  TestStudent {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student s1 = new Student("Cathy", 21, "Smithfield Drive", 72, "Nottingham Drive");
    Student.Address anotherAddress
          = s1.new Address(8, "Deerfield Way");     

    System.out.println(s1.toString());
 }
```

the output i'm getting is: Cathy
`student.Student$Address@2760e8a2` `student.Student$Address@4b48f7e0`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want nice output instead of something like `Cathy student.Student$Address@2760e8a2`, then you need to override the `toString()` method in your class `Address`.

Currently, the `toString()` method that you have is in class `Student`, not in class `Address` - carefully check the `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the toString()-Method of Adress as well.

```
 public class Address {
    public int number;
    private String street;
    public Address(int no, String street) {
        number = no;
        this.street = street;
    }

public String toString() {
return street + Integer.valueOf(number);
    }
```

Comment: @AnjunaTom When you concatenate an instance of a class with a String, it calls the `toString()` method of that instance in order to do that. Since there isn't one implemented for the `Address` class it uses the default implementation inherited from `Object`.

Comment: which is this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()